# Post AND page parameter for WP function

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, metabox, post-meta, parameter

Is there no post AND page parameter for WordPress functions? So would I have to create a custom post type to define post AND page?

For example, `add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );` you need to define what type of `$post_type`. The options are 'post', 'page', 'link' or a custom post type.

I'd like to define a meta box that applies to both the post and page. Surely copying and pasting the function and then replacing the $post_type with post and page would work but it wouldn't be very efficient.

I know that `is_singular()` defines both a post and page, but that is for a query.

Any ideas? I'd prefer not to install another plugin. One reason I am creating a meta box is so that I *don't* have to install a plugin.

Comment: You can't define a POST and PAGE custom type. By definition, a page supports hierarchy and a post doesn't. Incidentally, this is the major difference between post and page. I don't understand why calling add_meta_box twice is not efficient - though a bit more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you can't call add_meta_box() twice in a row and use the same function to display it both times; just change the `$post_type` parameter.

**Example**

```
foreach ( array ( 'post', 'page' ) as $post_type )
{
    add_meta_box( 'your_id', 'your title', 'your_callback', $post_type );
}
```

Comment: I just try to make my code as DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) as possible. For me, functions should be something that can be executed without having to repeat adding the code.

Comment: @Aimee Yeah i feel you.. but sometimes in wordpress or other peoples' frameworks in general, things don't always work out the exact way you would do it. I would say that in order to keep this as DRY as possible, you could define all the parameters in variables and then pass the same variables to each add_meta_box call. Then if you need to change anything, you only need to change it one place.

Comment: @Aimee I have added a code example to show how easy this is. :)